# Javascript / Ajax Error After Migrating To New Domain Name

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, javascript

I have migrated a client's site from their old spammy domain to their new domain that better represents their business. However, since the move, there seems to be some kind of Javascript/Ajax issue.

For example, I can't seem to switch tabs (on ajax pages), and the useful "quick edit" tool doesn't work at all. When clicking the quick edit link on any page I get this error in the F12 console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,inline-edit-po&load[chunk_1]=st,heartbeat,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,wp-sanitize,updates,shortcode,wp-backbone,media-models,wp-plupload&ver=5.5:292)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
    at n.fn.init.trigger (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[chunk_0]=hoverIntent,common,hoverintent-js,admin-bar,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-menu,jquery-ui-autocomplete,tags-suggest,inline-edit-po&load[chunk_1]=st,heartbeat,svg-painter,wp-auth-check,wp-sanitize,updates,shortcode,wp-backbone,media-models,wp-plupload&ver=5.5:48)
    at i (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Press F12, go to "Network" and reload your page. See if all the content is from the new domain or something is calling the old one